# When I download an excel I get weird caracters, because in my country we use accen marks, how can I repair this words, for ex: Ã“P DELANTERO DERECHO

Tags: excel

In my country we use acent marks, for example árbol.
But when I download the excel with more than 100.000 product names, the names are damaged with strange caracters.How can I repair this? Maybe its easy as changing the configuration of the excel?

Here is an example of damaged prodcut name:
"CAÃ‘ERIA CALEFACCION SUZUKI CARRY 1.0 SK410 1994"  what really should be is Cañería.

I tried this formula: =CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(160), "")) but didnt work.